# Reaction to the system messages discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I wanna make a command for my bot that would react to the system welcome messages.

*Using discord.py*

Is it possible to do that?
If yes, then help me. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(m):
    if m.is_system() and message.type == discord.MessageType.new_member:
        await m.add_reaction(...)  # change ... to your desired emoji
    await bot.process_commands(m)
```

This first checks if a message is a system message using [`Message.is_system`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.is_system) and then it also checks if the message type is the one that is sent when a new member joins. if both are true then it moves on to the add_reaction part. For detailed explanation of what format of emojis add_reaction can take see the [faq on how to add reactions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-can-i-add-a-reaction-to-a-message). Atlast it has `bot.process_commands` so that no matter if it's a system message or not it should just try to process the commands. if you are using discord.Client you can omit the last line